# Visually show file history

Tags: git, awk

I am trying to visually show a file change history.
      An easy way to do is to use gitk , while it is in text mode.
      I need a visual way, so I wrote following script:

```
git log --follow "$1"|awk '/commit/{print $2}'|while read ss; do git difftool $ss^! "$1"; done
```

`$1` would be my input for 
Suppose I have following commits related to `$1`

```
1b0e691e55caa8fd2b5dd6902f77c406fb68e648
d058c095f7e98a7ebe943c18f87ef087c723bb9f
c4d1769183ab6d852c624e71e6a0ca00dc3b6d13
```

But, when I run my script against `$1`, only these two commit are displayed,

```
1b0e691e55caa8fd2b5dd6902f77c406fb68e648
c4d1769183ab6d852c624e71e6a0ca00dc3b6d13
```

this one

```
d058c095f7e98a7ebe943c18f87ef087c723bb9f
```

is somehow skipped, I guess it is because the `^!` operator.
My intention is just to show the file change history in a visual tool, for example my favorite one: `kdiff3`.

Any alternative solution/help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
I am very sure, so, I run this script:

```
git log --follow "$1"|awk '/commit/{print $2}'|while read ss; do echo $ss; done

git log --follow "$1"|awk '/commit/{print $2}'|while read ss; do echo $ss;git difftool $ss^! "$1"; done
```

Below is the output:

```
458e7fd3c9ae03c27f6b7924e4725f91483a8f39
e17e1d44d75c73bca6cba27469f9d2a10938be33
1d19ee82dc4fc22e0576d9aee031a3f300b3fa10

458e7fd3c9ae03c27f6b7924e4725f91483a8f39

Viewing (1/1): 'src/main/java/substring_with_concatenation_of_all_words/SubstringwithConcatenationofAllWords.java'
            Launch 'kdiff3' [Y/n]:
1d19ee82dc4fc22e0576d9aee031a3f300b3fa10
```

You see, the commit `e17e1d44d75c73bca6cba27469f9d2a10938be33` is skipped.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve exactly? Can you show or mock up your desired output? (Also a reproducible repository would be helpful if possible.)

Comment: Since I have configured kdiff3 as my difftool, I want to pop up kdiff3 windows at every commit, to show its difference against its parent on that particular file.

Comment: are you sure it's skipped?  Can you check the output of the awk before piping to your diff tool.

Comment: For the record your problem here has nothing to do with your attempt to visualize anything and is entirely a problem with your loop not working the way you expect. Having written it that way would have been a better idea.

Comment: yes, while my intention is to visually show the change on file, I don't care how it would be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

See that `[Y/n]` prompt? `git difftool` is trying to read input and stealing a line from your pipeline.

You need to redirect to avoid that.

```
while IFS= read -r ss; do 
    echo $ss;
    git difftool $ss^! "$1";
done < <(git log --follow "$1"|awk '/commit/{print $2}')
```